# Limits Probability

Tags: probability

[image]

I'm having trouble seeing how the $x_1$ limits are worked out and how to visualize it on the graph.

Do you need to draw a graph? Could I do it without as I think its creating confusion.

Also were it says for any value of $x_2$, before it states the limits, what does this mean? and could you do it for any value of $x_1$ if the outer integral was with respect to $x_1$?

Lots of questions, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a number $x_2$ between $1$ and $2$.  Go ahead, pick one and write down its value so you don't forget it.  Next, find a number (there is only one) $x_1$
such that $x_1+x_2 = 2$. Don't forget that $x_2$ is fixed and you have written
down its value, and so $x_1$ should be easy to find. 
Now, plot the point $(x_1,x_2)$. That point is the left endpoint
of that horizontal dotted line.  Can you now figure out its other endpoint? 
Hint:
it lies on the line through $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$ whose equation you ought to be able
to figure out.

Now read the first sentence below your diagram.  Do you see that for *your*
chosen value of $x_2$, the dotted line is all the points $(x_1, x_2)$ such
that $x_1+x+2 \geq 2$ and $x_1 < x_2$?  That is, $$2-x_2 \leq x_1 \leq 2?$$
No? Did you forget the value of $x_2$ that you picked?  Do you remember
that $1 \leq x_2 \leq 2$?

To answer some of your questions:

- No, it is not *necessary* to draw a diagram but many beginners
  find it helps
- Yes, you can write the probability as a double integral in which
  the outer integral is with respect to $x_1$ but that will need to
  be broken into two subcases: $x_1 \in [0,1)$ and $x_1 \in [1,2]$.
  See if you can figure out why.